# Does product rule of covariant derivative apply for a scalar

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I'm proving a tensor identity and I wonder if it is true that

$$
\nabla_\mu \left( A^\nu B_\nu \right) = \nabla_\mu\left( A^\nu \right) B_\nu + A^\nu \nabla_\mu\left( B_\nu \right)
$$

where $A^\nu$ and $B_\nu$ are tensors and $\nabla_\mu$ is the covariant derivative?

It makes sense to me but I would like to confirm since the object here is a scalar due to the contraction and not a more "normal" tensor.

Comment: As far as I know, every kind of derivative in mathematics obeys the product rule. Every derivative is a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariant derivative obeys the product rule so yes, that does hold.

Also note that $\nabla_{\mu} (A^{\nu} B_{\nu}) = \partial_{\mu} (A^{\nu} B_{\nu})$, which is the correct covariant derivative for a scalar function - a type $(0,0)$ tensor. This can be seen by simply expanding the covariant derivatives in terms of partial derivatives and the connection, then noting the connection terms cancel:
$$
\nabla_{\mu} (A^{\nu} B_{\nu}) = \nabla_{\mu}(A^{\nu}) B_{\nu} + A^{\nu} \nabla_{\mu} B_{\nu} \\
= \partial_{\mu}(A^{\nu})B_{\nu} + \Gamma_{\mu \lambda}^{\nu} A^{\lambda} B_{\nu} + A^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} B_{\nu} - A^{\nu}  \Gamma_{\mu \nu}^{\lambda} B_{\lambda}\\
= \partial_{\mu}(A^{\nu}B_{\nu}) \ \ .
$$